# SQL Query in Access - Record still appearing even though it does not match criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm almost certain that the issue with my SQL code is something very minor, but I've been attempting to get this query to run correctly for hours to no avail.  I have a table that has 3 columns: Maker, Model, and Type.  I'm attempting to write a query that outputs the "Makers" that produce "PCs" or "Laptops", but NOT "Printers".  I'll post my code below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Product.maker
FROM Product
WHERE (((Product.type)="pc" Or (Product.type)="laptop")) AND ((Product.type)<>"printer");
```

This is a much smaller, modified table similar to what I'm working with:

```
maker   model   type
 A      1001    pc
 A      1002    pc
 C      1007    pc
 D      1008    pc
 E      2003    laptop
 A      2004    laptop
 E      3003    printer
 D      3005    printer
 H      3006    printer
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: What is the output to this query?

Comment: Does 'H' show up in your query? Because as written, 'E' and 'D' will show up because they also produce something other than 'printer'.

Comment: I apologize.  I completely left that part out.  'H' does not show up, but 'E' and 'D' do because they produce something other than a printer.  I need those to be eliminated as well.

Comment: You also need to be more clear with your tags. Are you using MySQL or MS Access?

Comment: Sorry about that.  I'm new to the site, as I'm sure you noticed.  I'm using MS Access.  I corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `NOT EXISTS` for this

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.maker
FROM Product P
WHERE (P.type="pc") Or (P.type="laptop")
AND NOT EXISTS
( SELECT 1 FROM Product P1
  WHERE P.maker = P1.maker
  and P1.type ="printer"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a "set-within-sets" query.  I like to approach these queries using aggregation and a `having` clause.  In your case:

```
SELECT p.maker
FROM Product as p
WHERE SUM(iif(p.type in ("pc", "laptop"), 1, 0)) > 0 AND
      SUM(iif(p.type = "printer", 1, 0) = 0;
```

The first condition counts the number of products that are "pc" or "laptop" and requires at least one.  The second counts the number that are printers, and requires that there be none.

This structure is quite flexible for a wide range of conditions.

Comment: Thanks!  This will certainly be beneficial to know as well.